# How to add BR between mysql record output

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html-table

I have a PHP page where user can select a province (ex. A, B) then click search. The output will be coming from the database. Now how can I group the data and add BR in between? example:

user choose province: prov_A
output:

```
program name: FLOOD CONTROL-prov_A-ALLOCATION
              FLOOD CONTROL-prov_A-ALLOCATION
              ROADS-prov_A-ALLOCATION
              ROADS-prov_A-ALLOCATION
```

I want to separate flood control from roads. Btw, I'm using Wordpress for this. A line break between will do. Also, the field 'allocation' from my excel file contain amounts like 7,000,000.00 or 1,000,000.00 but after importing to phpmyadmin it becomes 7.0 and 1.0. What data field should I use? 
CODE:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM projects where province = '$province'";   
                        //select database
                        mysql_select_db('pdmu');
//query for counting                        
$query="SELECT COUNT(proj_id) AS 'cnt' FROM `projects` WHERE province = '$province'";
$result=mysql_query($query); 
$row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
print_r($row2['cnt']); print_r('Records Found');
//echo $row2['cnt'] . 'RECORDS FOUND!';
                        $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

                        if(! $retval )
                        {
                          die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
                        }

                            echo "<table>";
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<th>";
                            echo "PROGRAM NAME";
                            echo "</th>";
                            echo "<th>";
                            echo "PROVINCE";
                            echo "</th>";
                            echo "<th>";
                            echo "MUNICIPALITY/CITY";
                            echo "</th>";
                            echo "<th>";
                            echo "NO. OF PROJECT";
                            echo "</th>";
                            echo "<th>";
                            echo "PROJECT NAME";
                            echo "</th>";
                            echo "<th>";
                            echo "ALLOCATION";
                            echo "</th>";
                            echo "<th>";
                            echo "PHYSICAL STATUS";
                            echo "</th>";
                            echo "<th>";
                            echo "FINANCIAL STATUS";
                            echo "</th>";
                            echo "<th>";
                            echo "REMARKS";
                            echo "</th>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                            echo $count . $row2;
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
                        {
                        echo '<tr>' . '<td>' . $row['prog_name'] . '</td>' . '<td>' . $row['province'] . '</td>' . '<td>' . $row['municipality'] . '</td>' . '<td>' . $row['proj_no'] . '</td>' . '<td>' . $row['proj_name'] . '</td>' . '<td>' . $row['allocation'] . '</td>' . '<td>' . $row['ph_status'] . '</td>' . '<td>' . $row['fin_status'] . '</td>' . '<td>' . $row['remarks'] . '</td>' .'</tr>';} 
                        mysql_close($conn);
```

Comment: Why so many echo's? Close php, write straight html, open it again when it's needed. Source will be more readable that way...and less.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM projects where province = '$province'";   
                    //select database
                    mysql_select_db('pdmu');
//query for counting                        
$query="SELECT COUNT(proj_id) AS 'cnt' FROM `projects` WHERE province = '$province'";
$result=mysql_query($query); 

?>

<?php $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

   while($row_result = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
   {
?>

<tr>
  <td><?=$row_result['your fields'];?></td>
</tr>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: thanks.. i'll try nesting mysql queries. how about the answer to my data field question? thanks.